# Is there a single term to define all sources (e.g., academic papers, grey literature, books, blogs, etc.)?

Tags: terminology

Is there a single term that includes all the following types of sources:

1. Scholarly publications
2. Government and think tank reports
3. News reports
4. Books
5. Blogs (written by academics)

For a paper, I used all of these sources. I am trying to tell someone how many articles I have read. Is "articles" a valid collective term for this?

> *"Reviewed 15 articles on .... These included scholarly publications, government reports, books, and blogs."*

"Sources" isn't a very clear term for those outside of academia:

> *"Reviewed 15 sources on ..."*

Comment: document ......

Answer (score 2):

You could use "References."